# If $E$ is measurable, then there is an interval $I$ such that $m(E \cap I) > \frac{9}{10} m(I)$ or $m(E^c \cap I) > \frac{9}{10} m (I)$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Here is my answer at the moment:

Suppose not! Then for all $I$, $m(E \cap I) \leq \frac{9}{10} \chi(I)$ and $m(E^c \cap I) \leq \frac{9}{10} \chi(I)$. Suppose $E$ has finite measure and let $E \subset \bigcup^{\infty}_{n=1} I_n$. Then
$$m(E) = m \left(E \cap \bigcup^{\infty}_{n=1} I_n \right) = m\left(\bigcup^{\infty}_{n=1} E \cap I_n \right) \leq m(E \cap I_n) \leq \frac{9}{10} \sum^{\infty} _{n =1} m (I_n)$$
Thus for all covers of $E$, $m(E) \leq \frac{9}{10} \sum^{\infty} _{n =1} m(I_n)$. But, by definition 
$$m(E) = \inf \{m(I_n) : E \subset \bigcup^{\infty}_{n=1} I_n\}$$
Hence 
$$m(E) \leq \frac{9}{10} m(E) \implies m(E) = 0$$
Now for $E$ with any measure, 
$$m(E \cap(-n,n) \cap I_n) \leq m(E \cap I) \leq \frac{9}{n}m(I_n)$$
Hence $m(E \cap (-n,n)) = 0$ for all $n$ where 
$$m(E) = m \left(\bigcup^{\infty}_{n=1} (E \cap(-n,n)) \right) \leq \sum^{\infty}_{n=1} m(E \cap (-n,n)) = 0$$
Note the same proof works for $m(E^c) = 0$.

I am not certain that this argument works, or is complete. Is there any more to add, or change to make this proof complete? Thanks in advance!

Comment: This looks right

Comment: With the correction that $$m(E) = \inf\left\{\sum_n m(I_n) : E \subset \bigcup^{\infty}_{n=1} I_n\right\}$$

Comment: The first part of your argument works even if $m(E)=\infty$. Your passage from finite measure case to the general case appears to be (unnecessary but) wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to do this is to observe that, according to the Lebesgue Density Theorem, we have, for almost every $x\in E\ $,

$$\frac{m(E\cap B_{1/n}(x))}{m(B_{1/n}(x))}\to 1\  \text {as}\ n\to \infty. $$

Therefore,  if $E$ has positive measure there must be an $x\in E$ and an interval $ B_{1/N}\ni x$ such that

$$\frac{m(E\cap B_{1/N}(x))}{m(B_{1/N}(x))}>\frac{9}{10}\Rightarrow m(E\cap B_{1/N}(x))>\frac{9}{10}\cdot B_{1/N}(x).$$